# Como remover os colchetes e virgulas ao imprimir uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como remover colchetes e virgulas do output ao imprimir uma lista em Python? Por exemplo, preciso que o resultado do código que fiz seja assim: `3 8 0 6 7` com os números separados por espaço e apenas isso, porém a saída está assim: `[3, 8, 0, 6, 7]`. Como removo essa formatação de listas?

Código abaixo:

```
numeros = input().split()
numeros = [int(x) for x in numeros]
maior_numero = max(numeros)

for i in range(len(numeros)):
    numeros[i] = maior_numero - numeros[i]

print(numeros)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para exibir os resultados sem colchetes e sem vírgula, basta implementar um laço de repetição exibindo os resultados na mesma linha, utilizando o `espaço` como separador. Neste caso o código ficaria:

```
numeros = list(map(int, input().split()))

for i in range(len(numeros)):
    print(max(numeros) - numeros[i], end=' ')
print()
```

Só para esclarecer a primeira linha do código se refere a um `input()` de múltiplos valores. Neste caso, quando executamos o referido código, o cursor fica **piscando** no canto superior esquerdo da tela. Neste momento, devemos digitar **todos** o valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A partir deste momento, será montada e armazenada uma lista na variável `numeros`. Em seguida o bloco `for` irá percorrer o range cujo tamanho é o comprimento da lista `numeros` e, a cada interação, será exibida a **diferença** entre o **valor máximo da lista** e o respectivo **valor de índice `i`**.

Answer (score 2):

A uma função chamada join que pode ser util nesse caso recebe uma lista de strings e retorna uma string.

Dentro da função é aceitado outras funções:

```
partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit',  
'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 
'translate', 'upper', 'zfill ... entre outras.
```

codigo:

```
exemplo = [3, 8, 0, 6, 7]

# resultado em uma variavel
var1 = "".join(map(str,exemplo))
#resultado : '3 8 0 6 7'
#ou diretamente no print
"".join(map(str,exemplo))
```

Join aceita  string.

Ou pode usar o meio de desenpacotar do python,descompacta a lista e retorna todos os elementos da lista.
representado pelo asterisco (*) e a configuração 'sep'.

```
print(*exemplo, sep=", ")
```